# Doubts about Multiplying Monomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, perfect-powers

I want to clarify proof of multiplying monomials.

1) $c * c ^2 = c^3$
sum power because power is shorter form of multiplication

2) $b^2 * b * 2b^6 = 2b^9$ 
2b) - Is it commutative property ?

3) $2^a * 2^b = 2^{a+b}$.
Why $2^{a+b}$ instead of $4^{a+b}$? Any proofs?

Thanks!

Comment: What's commutative property got to do with it? Commutative property implies that $a + b = b + a$ or $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, you always add the exponents.
It can be written as $c \cdot c \cdot c$. Tell me how many $c$'s do you see?

For the second one commutative property plays no role. If you expand all the monomials and multiply them you will find the answer.

The last one can be written as:

$$\underbrace{c \cdot c \cdots c \cdot c}_{a \text{ times }} \cdot  \underbrace{c \cdot c \cdots c \cdot c}_{b \text{ times }}$$

How many times do you see $c$? It's easy. $a+b$ times.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Didn't down-vote you, but the statement "commutative property plays no role" is very incorrect. $b^2\cdot b\cdot 2b^6 = b^3\cdot 2\cdot b^6$. Now what?